# Exception Handling through C# Web Services

Tags: c#, web-services, exception

This question relates to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/856993/proper-catching-of-specific-exceptions-through-web-service) which I asked earlier this week.

The answer given was correct, except I forgot to mention we were not using WCF, but regular XML Web Services, where there's no `[DataContract]` - all methods are simply prefixed with `[WebMethod]`.

Is there any similar way of handling exceptions using this service? The idea of FaultContracts would be nice, but it does not seem this applies to non-WCF services.

EDIT: Both server and client are written in .NET (C#), so it is not so much a matter of the format returned but the ability of the client program to identify and catch the proper exception instead of a generic Soap/FaultException.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. [Throwing better SOAP exceptions](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000054.html)
2. [Handling and Throwing Exceptions in
   XML Web Services.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ds492xtk(vs.71).aspx)