# Catching Database Exceptions

Tags: c#, web-services, exception

So I'm designing a *Web Service* and of course; I need this *Service* to automatically write to a *Database*.  Which is quite straight forward; but obviously *Sql* has a tendency to not play nice.

Which pretty much creates a nightmare when troubleshooting, not to mention through a *Web Service* would make it even more of a nightmare to debug.

So I checked the internet and stumbled across an article on Stack Overflow that talked about a *SqlHelper Class* that essentially had a massive list of these:

```
public static bool IsDuplicateId(SqlException sex)
{
    return (sex.Number == 2601);
}
```

So that implementation would be tedious, as you'd have to call all of these *Methods*.  However, someone answered with:

```
switch (e.Number)
    case 2601:
         // Do Something
         break;
    default:
        throw;
```

So I thought why not create a *Class* to handle a majority of these possible errors. With this particular implementation in mind:

```
public class SqlExceptionHelper
{
    public SqlExceptionHelper(SqlException sqlException)
    {
        // Do Nothing.
    }

    public static string GetSqlDescription(SqlException sqlException)
    {
        switch (sqlException.Number)
        {
             case 21:
                 return "Fatal Error Occurred: Error Code 21.";
             case 53:
                 return "Error in Establishing a Database Connection: 53.";
             default
                 return ("Unexpected Error: " + sqlException.Message.ToString());
         }
     }
}
```

So my thought process is I have a *Class* that can be reused to detect some common errors; and in other classes I simply `using SomeNamespace.ExceptionHelpers;` I could implement something like so:

```
public class SiteHandler : ISiteHandler
{
     public string InsertDataToDatabase(Handler siteInfo)
     {
          try
          {
              // Open Database Connection, Run Commands, Some additional Checks.
          }
          catch(SqlException exception)
          {
             SqlExceptionHelper errorCompare = new SqlExceptionHelper(exception);
             return errorCompare.ToString();
          }
     }
}
```

So essentially it should handle all those lovely exceptions; but I started thinking which isn't good.  **Is returning such Exceptions as a return good?  Can that in itself be bad? Or is this really the best way to handle such Exception catching through a Service?**

So my question boils down to:

> ```
>        Is this the best way to handle error catching through a Service?
> ```

Thank you for the help.

Comment: If your service returns a string for a good value and a string for the exception message, your client will have a nightmare to solve on its side

Comment: Also there is already a question like yours here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/856993/proper-catching-of-specific-exceptions-through-web-service?rq=1

Comment: @Steve My Google skills appear to suck, as I did not see that article. My apologies.

Comment: Sometimes it is useful to look simply at the related column on the right of this page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ideally web services should return relevant HTTP status codes, not exceptions. These are usually in the 200's (for OK), 400's (for errors that the user can fix themselves), or 500's (for server errors - these can be auto-retried too).

Based on your database error you get back, you can translate this to the appropriate HTTP status code. The description of the error code could be set to the exception message if you think it will help the user.

Comment: So essentially I should convert these Exceptions into HTTP Status Codes instead; not to sound naive.  But why is it important to return the HTTP Error Code, not just an Exception String?

Comment: Because Exceptions are a .NET-specific concept. The Internet encompasses far more languages, a lot of which do not understand Exceptions.

Comment: That actually makes perfect sense, thank you for the explanation.

Comment: Also, having said this, Microsoft does try to make it easier to return exceptions to the client (if the client is a .NET client) by using SOAP faults or Service errors (I forget the exact name). However, these will return an HTTP status code of 500 (or similar) and have the client unwrap the error description from the payload. This doesn't work nicely if you're using a non .NET client.

Comment: Yeah, it will be all .Net.  But I was just like "I feel like I'm doing something wrong."