# Update Database in the catch block

Tags: exception, language-agnostic

I have the following code

```
try {

  //Some code here that could throw an exception

 } catch (Exception e) {

  //handleExc contains code to Update the database

  handleExc();

 }
```

I am trying to achieve updating the database if an exception is thrown . **But my problem is updating the database inside the catch block could also throw an exception.**

handleExc() method contains code to update a row in the database in case an unexpected Exception is thrown.
I have made sure that it works all the time.

But however, now I am starting to think,

- **What if the database is down(hypothetically)?. My hosting provider isn't realiable**
- **How will I handle an exception in such a scenario since I have statements that update the database inside the catch block**.

I know for a fact that Exceptions for statements that could possibly throw an exception in the catch block will not be caught?

Is there an elegant way that I don't know of, that can be used in this scenario?

PS . I am using C# and asp.net and sqlserver but am guessing my problem can be generalised to any programming language

Comment: hi, did you try: try {} catch (SqlException ex) {} ?

Comment: I am not trying to catch an SQLException.

Comment: This could be quite relevant to you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15559508/catching-database-exceptions

Comment: As a backup, you might use a logging file or send yourself an email, but sometimes the best solution is to crash and burn as early as possible.

Comment: I thought of that too. But It is a payment processing page. Customers would be frustrated if it crashes. The need for updating the database is to change a column value from to 'payment not successful'.

Answer (score 0):

This is why databases (including MS SQL Server) support transactions.

You're trying to reinvent transactions, but carried out from the client side. The part you're discussing is the "rollback" phase. Databases implement this because there's no real way to do it in client code and have an assurance of its working.

With a real transaction, you can specify a series of actions that all need to take place together atomically--the DB server assures that either all of the things happen (as if they were all done at once) or else none of them happens at all.

The basic idea looks something like this:

```
begin transaction
change A
change B
change C
commit transaction
```

If something goes wrong during (say) change C, then the transaction will never be committed, and afterwards the database will be in the same state as if change A and change B had never happened either.

Essentially anything you attempt to hack together on the client side is ultimately going to run into problems--or rather, mostly into one problem: no matter how many levels of `try`/`catch` blocks you try to nest, you always have a possibility that you've done something that you later need to undo, and if you've lost connection to the server, you can't undo it any more. Worse, even if nothing goes wrong, you're likely to end up with the database being temporarily inconsistent, such as saying some of your inventory has disappeared without receiving a payment (or vice versa).

A well-designed database will generally implement the transaction using a transaction log. This means it starts by recording what the transaction will entail. Then it starts to carry out the changes specified by the transaction. If (for example) the database server were to lose power in the middle of the transaction, when it starts back up it can roll the database back to the state it was in before the last partial transaction started, then it can replay the transaction log forward from there.

I'll repeat: nothing you can do on the client is going to provide this level of protection for you data.

That said, let's consider what you'd need to do in some *other* situation that didn't involve a database. The main thing you need to do is decide on what you really *want* to do. If you've done something that you later need to undo, but the undo step might throw an exception, you're left deciding what you want to do then.

Most languages will let you nest a `try` inside a `catch`:

```
try { 
   make change A
}
catch (foo) {
    try { 
       undo change A
    }
    catch (bar) {
        // what to do now?
    }
}
```

Chances are pretty good that about all you can do inside the `catch (bar)` block is warn your user that things have gone horribly wrong, then log the error to notify you that something needs fixing. If it's (for example) an undependable connection to the server, you *might* want to just wait for a little bit and retry.